# Disable Javascript behaviour

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have disabled JS in my IE browser for testing purposes. The validation port is not working now which is good. But the page does a post back when I click a submit button.

Is this the correct behavior? Because All these days what I was believing is, even submit button call is being triggered by JavaScript? Am I wrong?

Comment: HTML forms could be submitted to the server before Javascript even existed. An `<input type="submit">` element does not require scripting in order to perform its job. So yes, you're wrong on that part.

Comment: please post it in answer section. This is what i expected i wil make this as an answer

Comment: How can i get the question as soon as it posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postback is done via JavaScript in MVC helper generated forms indeed. But if you disable JAvaScript and have button inside the form that is a type of `submit` it will still post the form without JavaScript. So this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Curious to know, How can i get the question as soon as it posted?